# automake error: Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated

Tags: perl, automake, autotools

After compiling and installing GNU automake 1.15, I get this error whenever I run automake:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex;
marked by <-- HERE in m/\${ <-- HERE ([^ \t=:+{}]+)}/
at /usr/local/bin/automake line 3936
```

I am running perl v5.22.0.

Comment: Problem seems to be fixes with automake 1.15.1

Comment: This problem has cropped up in ```Creating config file /etc/logrotate.d/postgresql-common with new version
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
  en_us
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
Setting up postgresql-9.5 (9.5.11-0ubuntu0.16.04) ...
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
```
Also because @bill-cole's answer is most relevant.

Answer (score 4):

In perl v5.22, using a literal `{` in a regular expression was deprecated, and will emit a warning if it isn't escaped: `\{`. In v5.26, this won't just warn, it'll cause a syntax error.

The author of the software will need to fix this before the 5.26 release. For now, you can safely ignore this warning.

See [perldelta](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.22.0/pod/perldelta.pod#A_literal_%22%7B%22_should_now_be_escaped_in_a_pattern) for details.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the change described in ["Perl Changes for 5.22"](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/RJBS/perl-5.22.0/pod/perldelta.pod#A-literal-%22%7B%22-should-now-be-escaped-in-a-pattern) but the solution suggested there of escaping the '{' is ***frequently*** not the right thing to do, depending on the intended logic of the regex.

This warning occurs when a regex uses a construct like "{,20}" which historically in some ***OTHER*** regex implementations has been interpreted as equivalent to "{0,20}", i.e. "a repeating series of the preceding atom, zero to twenty times."  In all cases where the intent is to quantify a repeat, this is broken in all modern versions of Perl, because interpretation of '{' followed by anything other than a number as a literal '{' has been explicitly documented since 5.8. Escaping the left brace in the case of an intended quantifier isn't the fix; adding the implied zero is.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed on 2016-04-01 (after automake 1.15, before 1.15.1).

From the [ChangeLog](https://fossies.org/linux/automake/ChangeLog):

```
  966 2016-04-01  Paul Eggert  <eggert@cs.ucla.edu>
  967 
  968   automake: port to Perl 5.22 and later
  969 
  970   Without this change, Perl 5.22 complains "Unescaped left brace in
  971   regex is deprecated" and this is planned to become a hard error in
  972   Perl 5.26.  See:
  973   http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.22.0/pod/perldelta.pod#A_literal_%22{%22_should_now_be_escaped_in_a_pattern
  974   * bin/automake.in (substitute_ac_subst_variables): Escape left brace.
```