# Fedora 23: "Unescaped left brace is deprecated" error in LaTeX

Tags: fedora, perl, latex

After updating from Fedora 22 to Fedora 23, I'm having trouble compiling anything with `biblatex` (`biber` as backend). Anything without `biblatex` compiles just fine, so I'm assuming it's something with the `biber` package for Fedora 23. Here's the error message:

```
Process started

Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\ding{ <-- HERE ([2-9AF][0-9A-F])}/ at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 207.

Process exited with error(s)
```

Is this something where I just have to wait until the code is updated, or can I do a workaround (not involving reverting the operating system to F22, of course, which worked just fine).

Someone else had a similar error [here (perl - automake error)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238539/automake-error-unescaped-left-brace-in-regex-is-deprecated), but I'm unsure how to fix this myself.

Comment: Alter that `}` in the regex to be escaped, `\}`

Comment: As I thought, but doing so then gives me the following error: `Backslash found where operator expected at /usr/share/perl5/Biber/LaTeX/Recode.pm line 207, near "$1\" (Missing operator before \?)`

Comment: Where did `$1` come from? That's not in your post. Could you post the full code somewhere? That module doesn't appear to be on CPAN...

Comment: Actually, I managed to fix it; I'll post an answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually ended up being two answers.

**Warning:** I'm relatively new to Linux, and I'm *not* a developer/coder of any kind. This will probably seem like child's play, in which case it's free to be deleted.

1. I fixed the error in the original file, fixing `{` to `\{` (@thrig had a slight error in his comment to the main post, which led me to making that same error before fixing it as shown here).
2. Doing so then pointed towards another file at `/usr/share/perl5/Biber/Input/file/bibtex.pm` with a similar error. Fixing this error then allows me to compile everything just fine.

What's confusing me still, however, is why it signalled these particular left braces; there are countless left braces in these files that aren't escaped, but I'm assuming that type of detail is above my head.